# Some Protractor tests started throwing element is not clickable error on Chrome - only on my local environment

Tags: protractor

I have a Protractor test that has been working fine for the past few months but no longer works this week. It keeps throwing the element is not clickable error. The test finds a button element on the page (that isn't initially visible upon page load, but will automatically scroll to it) and tries to click on it but fails.

My environment:

```
node v7.4.0
protractor v5.0.0
Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
chromedriver_2.26
Mac OS X 10.12.3
```

A sample of the HTML that's similar to the page I'm testing:

```
<article class="left-nav-content" ui-view="">
    <al-embed-flex id="flex-content" ui-view="html">
        <div class="settings">
            <div ng-if="ENABLED">
                <div ng-repeat="group in tree" class="settings-group" ng-if="group.types.length > 0">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="type in group.types">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="connect(type)">
                                <span class="icon-connect"></span>
                                <span>Connect</span>
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </al-embed-flex>
</article>
```

I have a method that basically does `$('.settings-group li button').click()`. When I run my test, I can see the page load, then I can see it automatically scrolls to the button (upon finding the element? or upon clicking it?) but immediately throws an error upon trying to click it:

```
 WebDriverError: unknown error: Element <button type="button" ng-click="connect(type)">...</button> is not clickable at point (1209, 680). Other element would receive the click: <article class="left-nav-content ng-scope" ui-view="">...</article>
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436421 (6c1a3ab469ad86fd49c8d97ede4a6b96a49ca5f6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64)
      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
      at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
  From: Task: WebElement.click()
      at Driver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
      at WebElement.schedule_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1921:25)
      at WebElement.click (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2002:17)
      at actionFn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:93:34)
      at Array.map (native)
      at actionResults.getWebElements.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:465:67)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
      at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)Error
      at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:463:23)
      at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:95:21)
      at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:841:14)
      at myClickButtonMethod.then.elem (protractor/page/MyPage.js:26:35)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
      at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7
```

I haven't modified this test at all in the past month. I've recently setup TypeScript for my project, but these test files haven't been converted to .ts yet. Interestingly enough, my 2 other team members can run this test without seeing the error I see, and one of them has an almost identical environment to mine.

I've looked up ways to solve this issue, and many suggest to explicitly scroll to elements before clicking on them? But I've also seen some say that scrolling is done automatically now, which looks to be the case when I watch my test run. I also have several other tests that seem to automatically scroll to elements that aren't visible and they seem to run OK.

Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons this may happen if chrome windows size is too small.

You should set window size in your config file

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah might be the window size would be a problem.

if you have full resolution in your system. then go for below.

```
onPrepare: function() {
browser.manage().window().setSize(1920, 1080);
}
```

otherwise stick to standard size of 1280, 1024 so that always all elements will be visible.